# Function definition not found

Tags: c++, mfc

I have code written in C++ using MFC.

In Mainfrm.h file i have these two declarations in public section of class CMAinFrame

```
void GenearteFile(void);//Dummy functions added to make toolbar button active

void ValidateServiceConfig(void);
```

In Mainfrm.cpp the header file is included. The definitions for both the functions is defined. Still green Squiggly lines appears in header file which says "function definition not found".

Comment: Does the project compile and link properly? (sidenote: (void) doesn't really have a place in C++)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is the definition of e.g. `GenearteFile` also misspelled the same way? Also, just because the IDE tells you something doesn't mean it has to be true. The only way to make sure you have no errors is to actually *build* the project successfully. If you can do that then you have no errors.

Comment: @stijn The project compiles properly. The project works well in VS 2008. But in VS 2015, it is just highlighting these lines.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes. No problem with the spelling. I looked at it before too. I don't see any error but why does it highlight?

Comment: Ah so it's some sort of intellisense problem

Comment: @Shiv Intellisense is not perfect. Take all issues, that it highlights, with a grain of salt. Especially, if the project compiles successfully.